# Автоматически исправлять все адреса со старого домена на новые

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Есть 2 домена, ссылающихся на 1 хостинг: http://olddomen.ru/ и http://www.newdomen.ru/

```
//Прописал в .htaccess следующее
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomen\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomen.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Признаюсь, не силен в .htaccess, но все работает. При вводе старого адреса - адрес меняется на новый. Но есть маленький недочет. Если зайти по старому адресу страницы, скажем:

```
http://olddomen.ru/home.php
http://olddomen.ru/home.php?write
```

Адрес заменятся на http://www.newdomen.ru/, а хочется, что бы заменялось так:

```
http://olddomen.ru/home.php -> http://www.newdomen.ru/home.php
http://olddomen.ru/home.php?write -> http://newdomen.ru/home.php?write
```

т.е. что бы не важно что было в адресе, что бы он просто в нем поменял домен и все. Можно так сделать?

p.s. если нет, просьба сказать прямо, т.к. нет - тоже ответ

p.s.2 ест-но эти домены я для примера взял

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomen\.ru**(.*)?**$ [NC] ?

Comment: Ещё через php можно (но не нужно)

    if ( detectOldDomain ) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: http://newdomain.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit();
    }

Comment: istem - что ж не в ответах? принять то как? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыт параметр `%{QUERY_STRING}` в конце.